# Web.Config Transformation XPath

Tags: web-config

I've done the usual checks for similar posts on here and Google (etc) but to no avail.

Basically I have a Visual Studio 2010 MVC3 solution that is using Web.Config transformations and for the most part they're working great.  However, I have some unit testing  bindings that I want removed and they're a little tricky because of their XML location.

Here is the cut down version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.HostAdapters.ASPNETAdapter" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                <codeBase version="10.0.0.0" href="file:///C:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%2010.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.HostAdapters.ASPNETAdapter.DLL" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                <codeBase version="10.0.0.0" href="file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.ExecutionCommon" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                <codeBase version="10.0.0.0" href="file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.ExecutionCommon/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.ExecutionCommon.dll" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                <codeBase version="10.0.0.0" href="file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource.dll" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="AjaxMin" publicKeyToken="21ef50ce11b5d80f" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.46.4422.26284" newVersion="4.46.4422.26284" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Esentially I want to remove the  nodes that contain a child  node with a name containing "Microsoft.VisualStudio".

So far I can get the nodes to empty using some verbose syntax in my transformation Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.HostAdapters.ASPNETAdapter" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.ExecutionCommon" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
                <codeBase version="10.0.0.0" xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" xdt:Locator="Match(version)" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly xdt:Locator="XPath(//runtime/*/*[not(node())])" xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This sort of works but gives me empty  nodes which I don't want.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: Nobody have any suggestions for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I have removed the unneeded dependentAssembly references, not sure if it is the best way, but it works for me:

in Web.config, add a name to all the dependentAssembly entries that are not required for production, I chose to use "QualityTools".

```
 <dependentAssembly name="QualityTools">
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.HostAdapters.ASPNETAdapter" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <codeBase version="10.0.0.0" href="file:///C:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%2010.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.HostAdapters.ASPNETAdapter.DLL" />
  </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly name="QualityTools">
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <codeBase version="10.0.0.0" href="file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll" />
  </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly name="QualityTools">
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.ExecutionCommon" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <codeBase version="10.0.0.0" href="file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.ExecutionCommon/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.ExecutionCommon.dll" />
  </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly name="QualityTools">
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <codeBase version="10.0.0.0" href="file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource.dll" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

In your transform file, add a transform to remove all entries with the name "QualityTools"

```
 <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly name="QualityTools" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />
</assemblyBinding>
```

Note the Transform is RemoveAll, to remove all entries with that name.